# How do I retrieve an Event Definition Key having the Journey specifications?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I'm trying to develop a REST service on a CodeResource that, among other things, expects to receive in the JSON payload a field containing the name of the Journey.

Based on the value contained in this field, I can retrieve the Journey information through the following API call endpoint:
`/interaction/v1/interactions/?name=name_of_the_journey`
the response I get is the following one:

```
    "count": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {},
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "journey-id",
            "key": "journey-key",
            "name": "name_of_the_journey",
            "lastPublishedDate": "2022-04-26T07:57:08",
            "description": "",
            "version": 1,
            "workflowApiVersion": 1.0,
            "createdDate": "2022-04-26T07:55:19.763",
            "modifiedDate": "2022-04-26T07:57:08.797",
            "goals": [],
            "exits": [],
            "notifiers": [],
            "stats": {
                "currentPopulation": 0,
                "cumulativePopulation": 0,
                "metGoal": 0,
                "metExitCriteria": 0,
                "goalPerformance": 0.0
            },
            "entryMode": "MultipleEntries",
            "definitionType": "Multistep",
            "channel": "",
            "defaults": {
                "email": [
                    "{{Contact.SendableAttribute.Email.\"Email Addresses.Email Address\"}}"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "analyticsTracking": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "analyticsType": "google",
                        "urlDomainsToTrack": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "metaData": {},
            "executionMode": "Production",
            "categoryId": 669417,
            "status": "Published",
            "definitionId": "definition-id",
            "scheduledStatus": "Draft"
        }
    ]
}
```

as far as I can see, in this response there's no information about the Event Definition of the Journey, which I need to retrieve in order to be able to inject the customers in the Journey using the endpoint for this purpose: `/interaction-experimental/v1/batchcontactevents` which requires the *EventDefinitionKey* as a parameter in its payload in order to work properly.

I know that this is an experimental API call, but even the classic one (`/interaction/v1/events`) requires the *EventDefinitionKey* as a parameter in its payload, thus my problem remains the same regardless of the API call I plan to use: starting from the Journey name, how can I retrieve the *EventDefinitionKey* related to the Journey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can get EventDefinitionKey by retrieving all EventDefinitions and filtering them by Journey's name with [this REST API call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/jb-api-specification.html):

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions?name=name_of_the_journey
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

2. Also you can do [the same call you were doing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html) but with an additional `extras=all` filter option, which will bring more info about your journey:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions?name=name_of_the_journey&extras=all
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

In the response, you can find EventDefinitionKey under the "metadata" object

Comment: Thank you, Niko. The filter option worked for me.
I tried retrieving all EventDefinitions and then filtering them by the Journey name, but it didn't work for me because I suppose there are too many Event Definitions on this BU. Nevertheless, the second option is fine!